# Laravel 5.2 загрузка проекта на сервер

Tags: laravel

[image: иллюстрация]
как правильно настроить на хостинг Laravel 5.2

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В идеале конечно стоит подыскать хостинг или VPS, который можно будет запойнтить сразу в папку public.

В вашем же случае есть 2 решения.

1 - Перенести все кроме папки public в отдельную папку, а содержимое папки public вытащить в корень. После этого прописать везде верное положение папки и проверить все конфиги.

2 - Прописать верно .htaccess  в корне,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```